Jmeter https sampler throwing 403/Forbidden due to .pfx certificate issue
I am trying to run a test but jmeter https samplers are throwing 403/Forbidden response. I have made some changes in system.properties file for the pfx file which are as below,
sun.net.http.allowRestrictedHeaders=true
javax.net.ssl.keyStore=RepackagedPFXFileForAzureAAHosts.pfx
javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=AAHosts
javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=pkcs12

pfx file is kept in jmeter bin folder. Jmeter version : 5.6.3
but still getting the error. Can someone please help me get this sorted.
Thanks in advance.

Your configuration seems to be valid, I can only think of just trying renaming RepackagedPFXFileForAzureAAHosts.pfx to RepackagedPFXFileForAzureAAHosts.p12
If it doesn't help enable JMeter debug logging and Java SSL debug logging and see if there are any suspicious entries in jmeter.log file and STDOUT
In case if 403 error is not connected with the client certificate it might mean that your script doesn't have correlation in place

Do I need to make any changes in the script (jmx) as well regarding this ?
